# Почему ошибка index out of range?

Tags: c++, олимпиада, index, числовые-последовательности

Числовая последовательность называется пилообразной если каждый ее член (кроме первого и последнего) либо больше обоих своих соседей, либо меньше обоих соседей. Например, последовательность 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 является пилообразной, а 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 — нет, поскольку 1 < 2 < 3. Любая последовательность из одного элемента является пилообразной. Последовательность из двух элементов является пилообразной, если ее элементы не равны.

Дана последовательность. Требуется определить, какое наименьшее количество ее членов нужно вычеркнуть, чтобы оставшаяся последовательность оказалась пилообразной.

Входные данныеЖ
В первой строке входного файла записано одно число N (1≤N≤100000) — количество членов последовательности. Во второй строке записано N натуральных чисел, не превосходящих 10 000 — члены последовательности.

Выходные данные:
в выходной файл выведите одно число — минимальное количество членов, которые необходимо вычеркнуть.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //делаем ввод
    int N;
    int b = 0;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> pila;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        pila.push_back(a);
    }

    //пишем, сколько раз нужно проверять
    for (int i = 0; i <= b + 1; i++){
        //проверяем
        for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++){
            if ((pila.at(j - 1) < pila.at(j) && pila.at(j) < pila.at(j + 1)) || (pila.at(j - 1) > pila.at(j) && pila.at(j) > pila.at(j + 1))){
                pila.erase(pila.begin() + j - 1);
                b++;
            }
        }
    }

    //ещё проверяем
    if (pila.size() == 2){
        if (pila.at(0) == pila.at(1)){
            pila.erase(pila.begin());
        }
    }

    //выводим
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы же **удаляете** из вектора элементы:

```
pila.erase(pila.begin() + j - 1);
```

но при этом все равно работаете до индекса `N-2`.

```
for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++){
```

А там уже вполне может не быть столько элементов, правда?

P.S. Правильность алгоритма не рассматривал.